# Updating each column on schedule by values from another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `users` table and two columns are having a relationship. The value of the first column is the monthly deductions of each user.

I want the data in the first column to keep auto increasing itself in the other column on a monthly basis.  Example: if user `A` has `$5` as their monthly deduction and has `$10` as their total_deduction in February, by march the total deduction should auto increase to $15.

I could use event in phpmyadmin sql I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, you can schedule an `event` for monthly deduction. Before creating an `event` make sure in your `mysql` you set `event_scheduler` is `ON` which in default is `OFF`.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Event: you can add fixed amount or user-wise deduction from another column.

#### 1) For fixed amount:

```
CREATE EVENT user_monthly_deduction
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
DO
BEGIN
  UPDATE test.users SET total_deductions = total_deductions + $5;
END$$
```

#### 2) From another column:

```
CREATE EVENT user_monthly_deduction
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
DO
BEGIN
  UPDATE test.users SET total_deductions = total_deductions + monthly_deduction;
END$$
```

For more details about `events-configuration` and `create_event` you can check this official document. [mysql-event-configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html)
and [create-event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html)

Comment: I love this, but something is missing. There is no universal figure to be added to all deductions as the $5 in the answer. Each amount to be deducted is unique to each user based on his/her deduction specified in another column. I want something like UPDATE users_table SET total-deductions = $row['monthly_deduction's] + $row['total-deductions'].

Comment: @godlovesme Just updated my response. In this case, only you need to replace `$5` to column name `monthly_deduction`.

Comment: Worked! All PHP programmers should see this. Thanks @ps1212